# Redirect to external URL with return in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, sms-gateway

I am trying to send one time password to a user using SMS INDIA HUB API.
For that purpose I need to redirect to a URL format:

http://cloud.smsindiahub.in/vendorsms/pushsms.aspx?user=abc&password=xyz&msisdn=919898xxxxxx&sid=SenderId&msg=test%20message&fl=0&gwid=2

If we load this URL, it will return some message. I need to get that message to.

I tried like this

```
$url = "http://cloud.smsindiahub.in/vendorsms/pushsms.aspx?user=wwww&password=eee&msisdn=9197xxxxx&sid=yyyyy&msg=rrrrr&fl=0&gwid=2";

return Redirect::intended($url);
```

But it is not directing to that link. It tries to load that URL in localhost.

Or is there any plugin to send sms using SMS INDIA HUB?

Can anyone help??

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You should be able to redirect to the url like this

```
return Redirect::to($url);
```

[You can read about Redirects in the Laravel docs here.](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#redirects)

Comment: I figured it out. You MUST `return` the redirect. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Also, I had to strip protocol 'http' or 'https' and add 'http' (because every site has it nowadays) to actually redirect to an external link.

Answer (score 60):

For Laravel 5.x and above

```
return redirect()->away('https://www.google.com');
```

as stated in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#redirecting-external-domains):

> Sometimes you may need to redirect to a domain outside of your
> application. You may do so by calling the away method, which creates a
> RedirectResponse without any additional URL encoding, validation, or
> verification:

Comment: This still works for Laravel 5.8 -> Updated link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#redirecting-external-domains

Comment: Still works for Laravel 6.x and 7.x Link from docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#redirecting-external-domains

Comment: as @DavidLartey , works under Laravel 8.x… do not forget to add `use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;`

Answer (score 30):

Define the url you want to redirect in `$url`

Then just use

```
return Redirect::away($url);
```

If you want to redirect inside your views use

```
return Redirect::to($url);
```

Read more about [Redirect here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#redirects)

### Update 1 :

Here is the simple example

```
return Redirect::to('http://www.google.com');
```

### Update 2 :

As the Questioner wants to return in the same page

```
$triggersms = file_get_contents('http://www.cloud.smsindiahub.in/vendorsms/pushsms.aspx?user=efg&password=abcd&msisdn=9197xxx2&sid=MYID&msg=Hello');
return $triggersms;
```

Comment: Hi, I used return Redirect::away($url) and it is working fine... Thanks a lot.. But how will I get the returned message after loading this url.. This url just giving message "{"ErrorCode":"000","ErrorMessage":"Success","JobId":"f136e997-8885-4cc3-a5b4-e9‌​ff394c0a4c","MessageData":[{"Number":"9197xxxxx","MessageParts":[{"MsgId":"9197xx‌​x2-21ac722669d248a5b75c73d79500e154","PartId":1,"Text":"Message."}]}]}".. It is not returning to my controller. Do you know, how to solve this problem??

Comment: return Redirect::to('http://www.cloud.smsindiahub.in/vendorsms/pushsms.aspx?user=chipsnbytes&password=w5p898e3&msisdn=919747320492&sid=SCHOOL&msg=The OTP for your WEB YOUR SCHOOL login is 5He6i. Please do not disclose OTP to anyone.&fl=0&gwid=2') is not working.... if we try to load then it directs to http://localhost/mywork/http://www.www.cloud.smsindiahub*****.com .... 
but return Redirect::away($url); is working.. but it is not returning to my controller after loading $url and sending sms

Comment: Can you provide the dummy url which you are trying to ?

Comment: It is working good for me and returning the result `{"ErrorCode":"7","ErrorMessage":"Invalid username or password","JobId":null,"MessageData":null}`

Comment: $url = "http://www.cloud.smsindiahub.in/vendorsms/pushsms.aspx?user=efg&password=abcd&msisdn=9197xxx2&sid=MYID&msg=Hello OTP&fl=0&gwid=2";
return Redirect::to($url);

I am also getting messgae that you got... But after sending sms, I need that response in my controllerer.... That mean after sending sms succesfully, url should redirect to my laravel controller... that is my problem now..

Comment: It is working good and the result is `{"ErrorCode":"23","ErrorMessage":"Parameter missing","JobId":null,"MessageData":null}` Do you want to return back to the controller after triggering sms ?

Comment: Cool, I have used it before. So, i can able to point your issue. By this way you can trigger sms to the client and you shall continue another operation in your controlelr.. I have updated my answer as updated 2. Kindly check it out

Comment: I have tried file_get_contents($url)... But It returns error.. failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request ... My code is                     $triggersms = file_get_contents($url);  
    var_dump($triggersms);

Comment: It returns me the proper error message while i return `$triggersms` . So i guess the url or  you trying should not valid. If you want me to help you more then i should see what you are trying ..

Comment: I understood the problem... This is working with the url I give to you... But problem is with msg parameter... My messgae format is "The OTP for your accout login is 5He6i" .. This messgae contains <space> .. I think this is the problem.. may I know if  you have any idea to solve this problem??

Comment: You should then encode the $url to fix it . If you give the final url which you want to try (you shall hide the credentials) i shall help you out.

Comment: the url is:  http://cloud.smsindiahub.in/vendorsms/pushsms.aspx?user=usrname&password=pass&msisdn=9197xxxx2&sid=ABCD&msg=The OTP for your  login is 5He6i. Please do not disclose OTP to anyone.&fl=0&gwid=2

Comment: I used str_replace and replace space with %20 ... now it is working fine... thanks a lot

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Redirect::away($url)`

Comment: Hi,  I used return Redirect::away($url) and it is working fine... Thanks a lot.. But how will I get the returned message after loading this url.. This url just giving message "{"ErrorCode":"000","ErrorMessage":"Success","JobId":"f136e997-8885-4cc3-a5b4-e9ff394c0a4c","MessageData":[{"Number":"9197xxxxx","MessageParts":[{"MsgId":"9197xxx2-21ac722669d248a5b75c73d79500e154","PartId":1,"Text":"Message."}]}]}"..  It is not returning to my controller. Do you know, how to solve this problem??

Comment: your welcome...  return Redirect::to($url); is just used to redirect within the site...

Comment: @Cishal:  
Hi, I used return Redirect::away($url) and it is working fine... Thanks a lot.. But how will I get the returned message after loading this url.. This url just giving message "{"ErrorCode":"000","ErrorMessage":"Success","JobId":"f136e997-8885-4cc3-a5b4-e9‌​ff394c0a4c","MessageData":[{"Number":"9197xxxxx","MessageParts":[{"MsgId":"9197xx‌​x2-21ac722669d248a5b75c73d79500e154","PartId":1,"Text":"Message."}]}]}".. It is not returning to my controller. Do you know, how to solve this problem??

Comment: in that case you should not redirect it.. u can do file_get_contents($url); in order to get the values back

Comment: I have tried file_get_contents($url); But it returns an error.     file_get_contents(http://www.cloud.smsindiahub.in/vendorsms/pushsms.aspx?user=fff&amp;password=ssdfs&amp;msisdn=97dddd&amp;sid=sdsd&amp;msg=sdas.&amp;fl=0&amp;gwid=2): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 4):

For Laravel 5.x we can redirect with just

```
return redirect()->to($url);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using InertiaJS, the `away()` approach won't work as seen on the inertiaJS github, they are discussing the best way to create a "**external redirect**" on inertiaJS, the solution for now is return a **409** status with `X-Inertia-Location` header informing the url, like this:

```
return response('', 409)
            ->header('X-Inertia-Location', $paymentLink);
```

Where paymentLink is the link you want to send the user to.

SOURCE: https://github.com/inertiajs/inertia-laravel/issues/57#issuecomment-570581851

Answer (score 3):

Also, adding class

```
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
```

and after, like this:

```
public function show($id){
    $link = Link::findOrFail($id);  // get data from db table Links
    return new RedirectResponse($link->url);  // and this my external link, 
}
```

or

```
return new RedirectResponse("http://www.google.com?andParams=yourParams");
```

For external links have to be used full URL string with 'http' in begin.

Answer (score 1):

For Laravel 8 you can also use

```php
Route::redirect('/here', '/there');
//or
Route::permanentRedirect('/here', '/there');
```

This also works with external URLs

Answer (score 0):

`return Redirect::away($url);` should work to redirect

Also, `return Redirect::to($url);` to redirect inside the view.