# Laravel 5.6 Redirect and Header not redirecting from inside controller

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-5

I'm trying to redirect to an external URL inside my Laravel Controller but it's not redirecting to another page.

I tried using header as well to no avail.

[Redirect to external URL with return in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28642753/redirect-to-external-url-with-return-in-laravel/28643019)

[Laravel 5: redirect to an external link outside of localhost/server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158074/laravel-5-redirect-to-an-external-link-outside-of-localhost-server)

This was in my response headers in the network console logs. I saw the external URL there but it was not redirected to.

```
alt-svc: clear
date: Thu, 04 Oct 2018 17:18:51 GMT
status: 200
strict-transport-security: max-age=31556926; includeSubDomains; preload
via: 1.1 google
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

A private function in the controller is the one used for redirecting.

```
private function processRedirect($gohere){
        return Redirect::away($gohere);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `$gohere` contains the full URL like this:

```
$gohere = "https://stackoverflow.com";

private function processRedirect($gohere){
        return Redirect::away($gohere);
    }
}
```